# Make Yosemite Installer USB drive that does not require internet access

Tags: macos, install

There are plenty of instructions on how to to make a Yosemite installer USB drive that work using either the [createinstallmedia](http://osxdaily.com/2014/10/16/make-os-x-yosemite-boot-install-drive/) program or [Diskmaker X](http://diskmakerx.com). However, when I take that drive to a machine which cannot be connected to the internet or to wifi, the installer tells me the OS cannot be installed because an internet connection is required. For all previous versions of the OS, it was trivial to do this with Diskmaker X because the installer did not require internet access.

Assuming this is possible, how can I make an installer USB drive which will not require network access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just noticed that 10.10.3 was available and tried it again. I am guessing that others noticed this bug and reported the problem for 10.10.2. createinstallmedia works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing a temporary OS onto a removable USB drive & use that to boot the other machine - then update it from that external boot using the regular installer.

Comment: What do you mean, "update it from that external boot using the regular installer"?

Comment: exactly what I said - update the internal drive from the external, using the already-downloaded Install OS X Yosemite.app